# Mysql  функция min/max над сгрупированными значениями

Tags: mysql

В запросе, который находит количество соавторов для каждого автора надо выбрать только авторов с минимальным/максимальным числом соавторов. (как дописать запрос?)

```
SELECT author.aut_id, author.aut_name, COUNT(saut.aut_id)
FROM author
JOIN article_author AS aut
JOIN article_author AS saut
ON ( author.aut_id = aut.aut_id )
AND aut.art_id = saut.art_id
WHERE author.aut_id != saut.aut_id
GROUP BY author.aut_id, author.aut_name
ORDER BY `author`.`aut_id` ASC
```

Comment: Хм. Может так?

     create view v as SELECT author.aut_id, author.aut_name,
      COUNT(saut.aut_id) cnt
     FROM author
     JOIN article_author AS aut
     JOIN article_author AS saut
     ON ( author.aut_id = aut.aut_id )
     AND aut.art_id = saut.art_id
     WHERE author.aut_id != saut.aut_id
     GROUP BY author.aut_id, author.aut_name
     ORDER BY `author`.`aut_id` ASC;
     select * from v join (select max(cnt) maxcnt from v) a ON v.cnt = a.maxcnt
     union select * from v join (select min(cnt) mincnt from v) b 
       on v.cnt = b.mincnt;

Comment: Спасибо. Существует ли способ попроще? В принципе в контексте одного сложного запроса.

Comment: UNION так не работает (не объединит разные столбцы), пишет все в maxcnt. Поправьте, если не так.

Но даже в общий столбец записать так получается быстрее:

SELECT * FROM v WHERE v.cnt IN ((SELECT min( cnt ) FROM v) , (SELECT max( cnt ) FROM v))

Для ускорения хочется сделать одним запросом на max/min. Что-то типа такого по смыслу:

SELECT * FROM v WHERE v.cnt IN (SELECT min( cnt ), max(cnt)) FROM v); (с двумя столбцами не работает, естественно). Как отправить в IN() вмето 2-x столбцов 2 строки с одного запроса?